# How can I make an ImageView scale to leave room for controls beneath it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I'm writing this app for image manipulation, and after the user chooses an image from the gallery, I have an options page with several controls on top and a preview of the chosen image in the middle. There is also a 'start' button at the bottom, but if the image is high enough, the button gets covered up.

I considered resizing the image to a specific height that works, but that height would change on different devices. Ideally I'd like the image to take up as much space between the controls and button, but I just can't figure out how to do that. I tried using a vertical tablelayout but that made no difference.

In this image, the emulator window is on the right.
[image: The emulator is on the right.]

Here's my XML. A tad messy but here goes:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10px"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView android:textSize="18px" android:text="GIF Options"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="FPS:"
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false" android:textSize="17px"></TextView>
        <EditText android:text="20" android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/EditTextFPS" android:numeric="decimal"
            android:singleLine="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:digits="2"
            android:width="50px"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Frames:"
            android:id="@+id/TextView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false" android:textSize="17px"></TextView>

        <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="70"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:id="@+id/EditTextFrames"
            android:numeric="decimal" android:singleLine="true" android:digits="2"></EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Saturation Boost: "
            android:id="@+id/TextView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false" android:textSize="17px"></TextView>

        <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:max="10"></SeekBar>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:text="Chosen Image"
    android:textSize="16px"></TextView>
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/optionspreview"
    android:isScrollContainer="true" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="22px"
    android:id="@+id/startbutton" android:text="Start!"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a RelativeLayout.

A oversimplified answer (since I don't know your layout) would be to have all your top controls inside a layout (say layoutTop), all your button controls inside a layout (layoutBottom) and having your ImageView in the middle:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layoutWrapper" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layoutTop" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   >
      <TextView 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Sparta!!!"
      />
   </LinearLayout>

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_below="@id/layoutTop"
       android:layout_above="@+id/layoutBottom"
       android:src="@drawable/empty_star" 
   />

   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@id/layoutBottom" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  >
      <TextView 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Sparta!!!"
      />
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The trick here is to notice how I created the id for layoutBottom. the "+" is not written when I am declaring the actual layout, but rather the first time it is used, i.e. in the ImageView.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do exactly this. What does the + sign mean?

Comment: The + sign means that you are declaring a new id.  In this case you are actually using the id before you are declaring the control, so it is declared the first time it appears in your XML file.  

(side note, this is my first answer post on this site, and it was accepted as the answer! Yay me! :) )  

Good luck mate!

Answer (score 1):

Post your (XML) layout. You are most likely using a `LinearLayout`. A `RelativeLayout` would simplify this. If you post your XML, I'll give you a hand converting it.

Edit: I would simplify your layout greatly. This layout is very complex and requires a lot of memory and processing to inflate. You can easily create this layout with one parent of a relative layout. The key is `android:layout_alignParentBottom` for correct placement.